# For loop column expression

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm doing average expression with multiple columns. Is there any way I can loop my list of columns so it can be like my sequence in example below?

```scala
val cols = List("col1", "col2", "col3","col4")
val expressions = Seq("avg(col1) as col1","avg(col2) as col1", "...")

df.selectExpr(expressions:_*)
```

**Pyspark Equivalent

```py
exprs = [avg(_col).alias(_col) for _col in cols]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```scala
val cols = List("col1", "col2", "col3","col4")
val expressions = cols.map(colName => avg(col(colName)).as("col1"))
df.select(expressions:_*)
```

Comment: I'm doing group by to that does have multiple columns df.groupBy(groupbycols).agg(*exprs) ** pyspark

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
  val cols = List("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4")
  val expressions = cols.map(c => avg(c).as(c))

  df.groupBy(cols.head, cols.tail: _*).agg(expressions.head, expressions.tail: _*)
```